# Angular2 http POST cannot get php file [404]

Tags: angular

In my console. This was the log given to me.

zone.js:1382 POST http://localhost:3000/app/service/getDataService.php 404 (Not Found)

But If I put this on url. It'll be downloaded. Which means this script exists on my app.

Here's what I have.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class GetNewDataService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private url = 'app/service/getDataService.php';

    getData(bangko) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
        let bank = `bank=${bangko}`;

        return this.http.post(this.url, bank, {
            headers: headers
        }).subscribe(res => {
            return res;
        });
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean, when you put it in the url of your browser? That's the case that it works?

Comment: If I put `http://localhost:3000/app/service/getDataService.php`. The script will be downloaded. However, If I put it on my http.post. It returns 404.

Comment: If you put the url in your browser, you are actually doing a get, not a post. That might be the problem.

Comment: @KwintenP No. If you put values in url. That would be a `GET`. What I mean is why I don't access the url using angular http post.

Comment: Did this ever get solved?